# Probability question involving simulations of picking balls from a bag

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

I’m working on a chemistry problem, which essentially translates to finding the answer to a related probability problem. However, my knowledge in probability is very limited and I'd be grateful if someone could help me out with it. The following is the problem:-

Suppose I have a bag containing $70$ red balls and $30$ blue balls. For the purpose of illustration, let’s call them $R$s (red balls) and $B$s (blue balls). Now, I am going to pick one ball at a time from this bag, without replacement. I define a **run** to be a sequence of consecutive $R$s (or alternately, $B$s) picked, along with the first $B$ (or $R$) that is picked. And I define a **red (or blue) run length** to be the number of consecutive $R$s (or $B$s) I pick in a run, before I encounter a $B$ (or $R$) or until the number of balls run out.

As examples, $RRRRRRB$ is a run (for simplicity, let me denote it by $R_6$ in shorthand) with red run length $6$, $RB$ is a run (denoted by $R_1$) with red run length $1$, $BBBR$ is a run (denoted by $B_3$) with blue run length $3$.

In each simulation, I keep doing runs until all the $100$ balls are picked out (since the balls are picked without replacement, the number of runs and the red/blue run lengths are both finite).

Let’s look at a typical simulation of ball-picking: $R_{50} R_{10} B_{28} R_9$. In this simulation, there are $4$ runs. The first run consists of $50$ consecutive red balls, until a blue ball is encountered. The second run consists of $10$ consecutive red balls until a ball is encountered. The third run consists of $28$ consecutive blue balls until a red ball is encountered. And the last run consists of $9$ consecutive red balls, and the simulation ends as there are no more balls to be picked.

It is easy to see that the minimum possible number of runs is $2$ (attained by $R_{70}$ followed by $B_{29}$, or $B_{30}$ followed by $R_{69}$) and the maximum possible number of runs is $31$ (attained by $R_1$ $30$ times followed by $R_{40}$, or $B_1$ $30$ times followed by $R_{70}$).

Also, the maximum possible value of red run length is $70$ and that of blue run length is $30$.

Now, I’m interested in knowing the probability distribution of the red and blue run lengths. For this, I believe that I must first find the expected value of the number of runs in a simulation. But I’m not sure how to proceed from here. So to sum up, the following are my questions:-

> $1$.  How do I find the expected value of the number of runs in a simulation?
>
> $2$.  For that expected value, how do I calculate the probability distribution of red and blue run lengths?

Comment: a good starting point could be this article: 
Schilling, M. F. (1990) The longest run of heads available at http://gato-docs.its.txstate.edu/mathworks/DistributionOfLongestRun.pdf

Comment: (1). The expected number of runs is easy using linearity of expectation. The first ball always begins a new run. For $k>1$, the $k$th ball begins a new run whenever it has a different colour to the $(k-1)$st. This happens with probability $2*30*70/(100*99)$. Since there are $99$ such $k$, the total expectation is $1 + 2*30*70/100$.

Comment: (2). What do you actually mean by "calculate the probability distribution"? The simple answer is that all possible outcomes of sequences of run-lengths (such as the examples you quote) are equally likely. The distribution is uniform. Thereafter there are plenty of questions you could ask: what is the distribution of the first run-length? what is the distribution of the longest run-length? etc etc

Comment: @James Martin: The basic idea of using linearity of expectation should work, but it is not the case that the $k$th ball begins a new run whenever it is a different color from the $(k−1)$st. The definition of run in this problem may be nonstandard. $RRRBRRB$ would be two runs, $R_3R_2$ even though there are three changes. Question 2 seems to be about the distribution of the lengths of the runs, and this is not uniform. Runs of length $1$ are much more common than runs of length $50$.

Comment: @DouglasZare: Ah, thank you! :) I was typing out a reply for James Martin, but you beat me to it. Yes, my second question is concerning the distribution of run lengths for $E$ runs, where $E$ is the expected value of the number of runs. Though now I realize that finding just the probability distribution of the number of runs is a daunting task, considering the sheer number of possibilities.

Comment: @AleZok: Thank you! I shall have a look at it.

Comment: How important is that definition of runs? I think it is more common to say that runs of red and blue have to alternate, and to call $RRRBRRB$ $R_3B_1R_2B_1$. That makes the analysis easier. Also, the expected number of runs doesn't have to be an integer. Do you really need the conditional distribution of the run lengths, conditioned on the median/mode number of runs? It might be easier to bound the unconditional probability that there is a run of length greater than some $L$.

Comment: Sure, your definition of runs is fine by me. Okay, I'll apply the floor function to make it an integer. As for the conditional distribution, ideally yes, I'd be preferring it, as it suits the related chemistry problem the most. But if it makes the problem easier, I'll be okay with an unconditional probability. Is it possible to obtain this for any general $L \in \{1,...69\}$ (in the case of red balls)? And thank you for taking the time to help me out, I really appreciate it. :)

Comment: With the other definition of runs, James Martin's calculation applies, and the average number of runs is $43$.

Comment: But it doesn't seem to add up, as the maximum possible value of the number of runs is still $31$.

Comment: The maximum number of runs becomes $61$ with the other definition.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't see it. Can you provide me an example of a simulation that has $61$ runs? Or just greater than $31$ runs?

Comment: $RBRBRBR$ has $7$ runs under the other definition. $(RB)^{30}R^{40}$ has $61$.

Comment: Oh okay, I get it now. Rather silly of me, sorry.

Comment: sorry for the hasty misreading - thanks for setting me right guys!

Comment: There is a standard way to count the number of patterns with no run of $R$s longer than some value. The expression is not closed form, but it can be written as a single sum. Dividing by $ 100 \choose 30 $ gives the probability that no run of $R$s is longer than the given value. Offhand, I don't know how to restrict the runs of $R$ and $B$ simultaneously in a closed form expression, but you can use dynamic programming to compute the count rapidly.

Comment: Oh, I see. Could you provide me a reference to that expression? And thank you for your help! :)

Comment: Choosing $70$ $R$s and $30$ $B$s is equivalent to choosing $31$ nonnegative numbers which add up to $70$. This is the stars and bars argument. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29 By adding $1$ to each, you get $31$ positive integers adding up to $101$. If you use the restriction that you don't have a streak of $10$ or more $R$s in a row, this corresponds to $31$ nonnegative numbers less than $10$ adding up to $70$. Adding $1$, you have $31$ numbers from $1$ to $10$ adding up to $101$. This is like asking how many ways there are to roll $31$ $10$-sided dice to get

Comment: a total of $101$. This version of the problem is more common. You can see the expression (I think due to de Moivre) in a few places though in some there are errors such as in the upper limit of the summation. See http://www.quora.com/How-do-you-find-the-number-of-ways-the-sum-of-k-dice-rolls-equals-S-for-an-n-sided-fair-die or the top of page 30 here http://www.stat.ualberta.ca/~schmu/stat371/371notes.pdf.